# Analysis related to topology

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Prove that $$\lim_{h→0} ∫_{-\infty}^\infty \left| f(t+h) - f(t)\right|\, dt = 0.$$ 
where $f(t)$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$, satisfying $∫_{-\infty}
^\infty |f(t)|dt < ∞$.

Comment: Do you know that $C_c(\mathbb{R})\subseteq L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is dense?

Comment: Sorry, no...could you please tell me the detail? And how is the fact be useful for the problem?

Comment: Do you know the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: @xpaul yup..but I don't know hot to connect it to this problem. Btw, sorry for being late to reply.